# next and previous button for table in for loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

when I click on next button display the rows ..I want to display 5 table in first page then when click next display next five table ..
its get this tables from database in for loop so its take the same class

PHP

```
$student = "";
foreach ($sql as $sq) {
    if ($student != $sq["Student_ID"]) {
        $student = $sq["Student_ID"];
        echo ' <table class="trs" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #676767;width: 700px;"> <tr><td> <label>
        <input type="submit" class="' . $student . '" style="display: none;"onclick="myFunction()" id="hhh">
            <img  style ="width: 20px"src="images/up-arrow.png"id="file"><br>
        </label></td>';
        echo '<td id="fff">' . $sq["Student_ID"] . '</td></tr>';
    }
    echo ' <tr style="display:none;" class="'. $student . '" >';
    echo '<td class="myDIV">' . $sq["exam_dates"] . '</td>';
    echo '<td class="myDIV">' . $sq["exam_days"] . '</td>';
    echo '<td class="myDIV">' . $sq["Subject_name"] . '</td></tr>';
}
?>
</table>
<a id="next">next</a>
<a id="prev">prev</a>`
```

and this js

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $(".file1").click(function () {
        $(".import").show();
    });

    $("*#hhh").click(function () {
        console.log($(this).attr('class'));
        var className = $(this).attr('class');
        $("tr."+className).slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
   $(document).ready(function () {
   $(".trs tr").each(function(e) {
          if (e != 0)
              $(this).hide();
       });
       $("#next").click(function(){
          if ($(".trs tr:visible").next().length != 0)
              $(".trs tr:visible").next().show().prev().hide();
           else {
            $(".trs tr:visible").hide();
            $(".trs tr:first").show();
        }
        return false;
    });

    $("#prev").click(function(){
        if ($(".trs tr:visible").prev().length != 0)
            $(".trs tr:visible").prev().show().next().hide();
        else {
            $(".trs tr:visible").hide();
            $(".trs tr:last").show();
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

it should be different class for each table

Comment: Please post a working example after reading: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) - Replace the PHP bits with actual HTML Table that it outputs. It doesn't sound like PHP is relevant here.

Comment: **Id should be unique** So don't use the same id for more than one element .. I talk here about `#hhh` .. Also `$(this).attr('class')` is not a good way to check for class .. if you need to check for class use `.hasClass('Something')` But If you want to pass values use `data-` attribute

Comment: ok but how I can give id unique if its in for loop?

Comment: You could use a [class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/class) instead.